# Examples of two dimensional heat conduction problems

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer, thermal-conduction

Can anyone give me some examples from real life, where the heat transfer can be modelled as two dimensional. Also if one could explain why we can model it as 2 dimensional.

Comment: You had the one dimensional question earlier, but found it also here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/669364

Comment: anything axisymmetric

Answer (score 4):

You can model heat conduction in two dimensions when there is no heat flux in the third dimension.

(Sorry if that sounds trite, but IMO that part of the question is so trivial it shouldn't be necessary for anyone to ask it on an *engineering* forum!)

An example would be heat flow in an electrical conductor that is heated by an electric current, where the heat is generated internally in the conductor and flows towards the surface, but there is no heat flow along the *length* of the wire.

Note, for a conductor with a circular section you might consider this as 1D heat flow in cylindrical coordinates, not 2D heat flow in cartesian coordinates, but suppose the conductor had a square cross section not a circular one.

Comment: as your 1D mention alludes, some problems can be collapsed a dimension, not only for a case where out of plane is zero but also if a dimension is identical or sometimes even can be expressed in terms of another.  for example one might only make distinctions of radial and axial axes even though radial would encompass anything in a cartesian plane.  Here the tangential is usually zero or otherwise inconsequential.  it comes down to what you call a dimension.

Answer (score 2):

> ... some examples from real life ...

A simple heat exchanger. The fluid travels in a tube carrying enthalpy content along the length of the tube. Heat flows radially outward.

Your blood vessels. Enthalpy flows along the vessel. Heat leaves outward from the vessels.

Certain types of ice-making machines. Water flows over a cold plate. Heat is extracted into the plate due to the temperature difference between the hotter water and the colder plate. The temperature of the water decreases as it flows from the inlet to the bottom (where it becomes ice).

> ... why we *can* model it as 2 dimensional

My emphasis added. You do not ask why we *must* or why we *should*.

First, recall that we have three types of coordinate systems, Cartesian, cylindrical, and spherical. Your question makes no distinction. Each system has three dimensions. Again, your question makes no distinction.

We *must* model certain systems in two dimensions because distinct temperature differences appear those two dimensions and not in the third. Take the ice plate example or the blood vessel example or the heat exchanger example. Ask yourself what the temperatures are at the start and end points of the fluid flow. What about the temperature differences between the flowing fluid and the surroundings?

We *cannot* model systems solely in two dimensions when we can find significant or controlling temperature differences or gradients in all three directions regardless of the coordinate system. The accuracy of the answer will demand a 3-D model.

We *should not* model systems that have only one direction of a temperature difference or gradient using a 2-D model. The end result is the nonsensical answer that no heat flows when we have no temperature difference or gradient in that direction.

We *may* model 2-D systems as 1-D to simply the problem. The conditions to do so require assumptions about the relative differences in temperature or temperature gradient along one direction versus along the other. In such cases, for the direction that is neglected, we may state that we are doing a lumped analysis. An example is the analysis of a fin on a hot wall extending into a cooler fluid. Heat flows along the extended length of the fin. It also flows out the sides of the fin. To simply the analysis in certain cases, we can make a valid assumption that heat flow out the sides is negligible compared to heat flow along the length. The 2-D problem becomes a 1-D problem.